# Instantiate new NSData of specific length in swift

Tags: swift

Is there a better way to come up with an `NSData` or `NSMutableData` in Swift than doing what I did here?

The best I could come up with was:

```
    let initBytes : [UInt8] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
    let intiData = NSMutableData(bytes: initBytes, length: initBytes.count)
```

Is there a 1 line way to do this that I some how missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `init?(length length: Int)`

> Initializes and returns an NSMutableData object containing a given number of zeroed bytes.

```
let data = NSMutableData(length: 8)!
```